# Create and bind template user control to behave like a gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, templates, gridview, user-controls

I want to create an user control where I cant set columns as we do on a grid view.

Something like shown below

```
<uc:MyGrid runat="server" ID="_grid">
    <Columns>
        <GridViewDataColumn  FieldName="Client"
            Width="45" VisibleIndex="1">
            <Settings AutoFilterCondition="Contains" />
        </GridViewDataColumn>
        <GridViewDataColumn FieldName="Folder"
            Width="45" VisibleIndex="2">
            <Settings AutoFilterCondition="Contains" />
        </GridViewDataColumn>
    </Columns>
</uc:MyGrid>
```

As I'm using DevExpress controls I tried to create a template with the type of GridViewColumnCollection but it gives me an error, saying that I'm not using the INamingContainer inteface.

Anyone can point me to the direction to follow?

Answer (score 0):

When you develop templated controls, you should implement this interface to avoid naming conflicts on a page.
checkout this link [INamingContainer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.inamingcontainer.aspx)